# Installing Quantstrat in a recently updated R in Fedora Linux

Tags: r, quantstrat, fedora-25, blotter

I have updated my Fedora Distribution recently, and R was updated too. I re installed most of the packages, but I couuldnt install blotter and quantstrat.

How can I solve this issue? Thank you!

The error I get is the following one:

```
install.packages("quantstrat", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

**Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘quantstrat’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)**

**My sessioninfo is the folowing:**

```
> sessionInfo()
```

R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Fedora 25 (Twenty Five)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_AR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=es_AR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_AR.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_AR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_AR.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=es_AR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=es_AR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0

Comment: This doesn't help, but see discussion on [Fedora devel mailing list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44834208/479426) — by policy, the update to 3.4.0 shouldn't have gone into Fedora 25 (and arguably not into Fedora 26 at this stage), but we didn't notice until it went out.

Comment: @mattdm if you're a developer on this package, is there any chance you could make .tar.gz files of quantstrat and blotter old versions available for download? [R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=316) has .zip files for Windows but no option to download .tar.gz

Comment: I am not a developer on that package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem likely isn't an issue related to Fedora linux. Install quantstrat from souce via github, where the latest code resides:

```
library(devtools) # need devtools to use install_github
install_github("braverock/quantstrat")
```

Comment: For single line command in Docker file I use: 
RUN R -e "require(devtools); install_github('braverock/blotter')"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!! I have successfully intalled it! Both in my Fedora and in W10 notebook.

I installed a weeks ago. I had to wait for the new TS package to be available on cran, since blotter required it.

Thank you very much!